# I/O Loop in Haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, io, polynomial-math

I am currently working on this Haskell problem and I seem to be stuck.

Write a function, evalpoly, that will ask a user for the degree of a single variable polynomial, then read in the coefficients for the polynomial (from highest power to lowest), then for a value, and will output the value of the polynomial evaluated at that value.  As an example run:

```
> evalpoly
What is the degree of the polynomial: 3
What is the x^3 coefficient: 1.0
What is the x^2 coefficient: - 2.0
What is the x^1 coefficient: 0
What is the x^0 coefficient: 10.0
What value do you want to evaluate at: -1.0
The value of the polynomial is 7.0
```

As of now, I have this:

```
evalpoly :: IO ()
evalpoly  = putStr "What is the degree of the polynomial: " >>
          getLine >>= \xs ->
          putStr "What is the x^" >>
          putStr (show xs) >>
          putStr " coefficient: " >>
          putStrLn ""
```

How would I go about adding the loop and calculations?

Comment: I've removed your reimplementation of the `Prelude`, as it didn't seem relevant to your question. If you think it is relevant, feel free to revert the edit and add a short explanation of why we should pay special attention to your version of the standard functions.

Comment: You can loop an IO action over a list with `mapM` (probably `mapM_` is more useful to you here). If `cs` are the coefficients of the polynomial and `x` is the x-value, then `sum $ zipWith (*) (reverse cs) $ iterate (*x) 1` is the value of polynomial at x.

Answer (score 4):

### Warning:

I spoil this completely so feel free to stop at any point and try to go on yourself

---

Instead of pushing it all into this single function I will instead break this down into smaller tasks/functions.

So let's start with this.

### 1. Input

On obvious part is to ask for an value - and if we are on it we can make sure that the user input is any good (I am using [`Text.Read.readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) for this:

```
query :: Read a => String -> IO a
query prompt = do
  putStr $ prompt ++ ": "
  val <- readMaybe <$> getLine
  case val of
    Nothing -> do
      putStrLn "Sorry that's a wrong value - please reenter"
      query prompt
    Just v -> return v
```

please note that I appended the `": "` part already so you don't have to do this for your `prompt`s

---

having this all the questions to your user become almost trivial:

```
queryDegree :: IO Int
queryDegree = query "What is the degree of the polynomial"

queryCoef :: Int -> IO (Int, Double)
queryCoef i = do
  c <- query prompt
  return (i,c)
  where prompt = "What is the x^" ++ show i ++ " coefficient"

queryPoint :: IO Double
queryPoint = query "What value do you want to evaluate at"
```

please note that I provide the powers together with the coefficients - this make the calculation a bit easier but is not strictly necessary here I guess (you could argue that this is more than the function should do at this point and later use `zip` to get the powers too)

---

Asking all the inputs is now really easy once you've seen [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) and what it can do - it's the point where you usually would want *to write a loop*:

```
queryPoly :: IO [(Int, Double)]
queryPoly = do
  n <- queryDegree
  mapM queryCoef [n,n-1..0]
```

### 2. Evaluation

Do evaluate this I just need to evaluate each term at the given point (that is each *power, coefficient* pair in the list) - which you can do using `map` - after we just need to sum this all up (`sum` can do this):

```
evaluate :: Double -> [(Int, Double)] -> Double
evaluate x = sum . map (\ (i,c) -> c*x^i)
```

### 3. Output

Is rather boring:

```
presentResult :: Double -> IO ()
presentResult v = putStrLn $ "The vaule of the polynomial is " ++ show v
```

### 4. Getting it all together

I just have to ask for the inputs, evaluate the value and then present it:

```
evalpoly :: IO ()
evalpoly = do
  p <- queryPoly
  x <- queryPoint
  presentResult $ evaluate x p
```

### 5. Test-Run

Here is an example run

```
What is the degree of the polynomial: 3
What is the x^3 coefficient: 1.0
What is the x^2 coefficient: -2.0
What is the x^1 coefficient: Hallo
Sorry that's a wrong value - please reenter
What is the x^1 coefficient: 0
What is the x^0 coefficient: 10.0
What value do you want to evaluate at: -1.0
The vaule of the polynomial is 7.0
```

---

### complete Code

Note that I like to enter the no-buffering because I run into trouble on Windows occasionally if I don't have it - you probably can live without

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (mapM)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import System.IO (BufferMode(..), stdout, hSetBuffering)

query :: Read a => String -> IO a
query prompt = do
  putStr $ prompt ++ ": "
  val <- readMaybe <$> getLine
  case val of
    Nothing -> do
      putStrLn "Sorry that's a wrong value - please reenter"
      query prompt
    Just v -> return v

queryDegree :: IO Int
queryDegree = query "What is the degree of the polynomial"

queryCoef :: Int -> IO (Int, Double)
queryCoef i = do
  c <- query prompt
  return (fromIntegral i,c)
  where prompt = "What is the x^" ++ show i ++ " coefficient"

queryPoint :: IO Double
queryPoint = query "What value do you want to evaluate at"

queryPoly :: IO [(Int, Double)]
queryPoly = do
  n <- queryDegree
  mapM queryCoef [n,n-1..0]

evaluate :: Double -> [(Int, Double)] -> Double
evaluate x = sum . map (\ (i,c) -> c*x^i)

presentResult :: Double -> IO ()
presentResult v = putStrLn $ "The vaule of the polynomial is " ++ show v

evalpoly :: IO ()
evalpoly = do
  p <- queryPoly
  x <- queryPoint
  presentResult $ evaluate x p
```