# to evaluate polynomial in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function(`eval`) to evaluate polynomial.

```
eval coeffs value = .......
```

`coeffs` is list of coefficents.

`value` is for *x* in math

> Ex) to calculate
>   3x^2 + 2x + 1 with x=20

`coeffs` is stored reverse order.

when I type coefficient like above, it is stored like this `[1,2,3]`

program working like this and last part is wrong (the value of the polynomial):
here is my code

```
getCoeff 0 ls = do  return ls

getCoeff n ls = do  putStr "What is the x^"
            putStr (show(n-1))
            putStr " coefficient: "
            v <- getLine
            w <- getCoeff (n-1) ((read v :: Float):ls)
            return w


evalpoly = do   putStr "What is the degree of polynomial: "
        v <- getLine    
        l <- (getCoeff ((read v :: Int)+1) [])
        putStr "What value do you want to evaluate at: "
        x <- getLine    
        putStr "The value of the polynomial is: "
        putStr (show (polyEvaluate (l) (read x :: Float)))
        putStr "\n"

eval [] x = 0.0
eval (l) x =
```

---

```
What is the degree of polynomial: 2
What is the x^2 coefficient: 3
What is the x^1 coefficient: 2
What is the x^0 coefficient: 1
What value do you want to evaluate at: 20
The value of the polynomial is 1241.0
```

how can I evaluate the polynomial with coefficient and x value?

Comment: Your question could use a bit of work, it looks like your formatting is off and your wording isn't very clear.  Do you already have a function `eval`, or are you tasked to write one?

Comment: well I guess it's your homework/exercise so you should start by telling us what you tried - do you even have the representation set up? Show us some code :D

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438057/i-o-loop-in-haskell/36441613#36441613 (**caution** the link will spoil the complete homework)

Comment: how can i make eval function with list of coefficient and value?

Comment: What is the definition of `polyEvaluate`?

Answer (score 3):

some hints...

you can write a series of powers easily

```
powers n = iterate (*n) 1

> take 10 $ powers 2
[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
```

and combine this with your coefficients

```
> zip [1,2,3] $ powers 20 
[(1,1),(2,20),(3,400)]
```

you have to think what to do to change this to a sum of product of the pairs (use zipWith)